# shirt is cut slim and

Tags: word-usage, word-order

Are these sentences correct:

1. His shirt is cut slim and white.
2. His shirt will be cut slim and white.

The meaning seems clear, but I'd say 'white and cut slim'. The order of the words doesn't seem natural to me. I get the feeling that the sentences are telling us that the shirt is/will be cut slim and it is/will be cut white! That is nonsensical, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with you, "His shirt is white and cut slim" is a much better word order since the other word orders create confusion with how to parse the "and", creating a [Garden Path Sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence).  That said, Garden Path Sentences aren't grammatically *wrong*, just extremely confusing and highly discouraged.  Once you parse "His shirt will be cut ... white" and notice that this is nonsensical, you must go back and reparse the sentence.  Once you reparse the sentence, ("His shirt will be A) cut slim, and B) white.") it can be understood.

So all three are *technically* grammatically correct, but please avoid both 1 and 2 whenever possible, or you will (briefly) cause exactly the confusion you mentioned.